# JavaScript : Alphanumeric REGEX pattern

Tags: javascript

My regex pattern for alphanumeric word is as given below :

`/([A-Za-z0-9])*$/`

Is "testuser" a valid input string for the above pattern?

Comment: You might check out [rubular](http://rubular.com) (I think the javascript equivalent is called scriptular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use character class.

So use: `/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/`

And yes, `testuser` is a valid input for the above regex.

Comment: Is "testuser" a valid input string for alphanumeric string, Or is it mandatory to have numbers in it?

Comment: @SuganyaSrinivasan, yes it is valid